# Searching efficiently within an HTML/XML file

Tags: html, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

**usecase** :     I have an html file & I need to search for a text within that.

Say my file is -:

```
</script> <!-- right side bands --> </div> </div> <div class="fclear"></div> <div class="fk-mainfooter fksk-mainfooter tpadding20 bpadding5 new-vd" id="fk-mainfooter-id"> <div class="fk-content fksk-content bpadding10"> <div class="line tpadding20 bpadding20 footer-dark-top-border"> <div class="unit fk-footer-links-container"> <div class="unit size1of4"> <span class="fk-footer-sub-head fk-footer-unit"><strong>Help</strong></span> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/help/payments">Payments</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/help/savedcard_how">Saved Cards</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/help/shipping">Shipping</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/help/cancellation-returns">Cancellation &amp;
 Returns</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/help">FAQ</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="https://seller.flipkart.com/fiv">Report Infringement</a> </div> <div class="unit size1of4"> <span class="fk-footer-sub-head fk-footer-unit"><strong>Flipkart</strong></span> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/contact">Contact Us</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/about-us">About Us</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" target="_blank" href="/ol?link=http%3A%2F%2Fflipkartcareers.com%2F">Careers</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/ol?link=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.flipkart.com%2F">Blog</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/s/press">Press</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" target="_blank" href="http://slashn.flipkart.net/">Slash N</a> </div> <div class="unit size1of4 required-tracking" data-tracking-id="ch_vn"> <span class="fk-footer-sub-head fk-footer-unit"><strong>Flipkart eBooks</strong></span> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/ebooks/gettingstarted" target="_blank">eBooks Quick Start Guide</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/help/flyteeBookfaq" target="_blank">eBooks FAQ</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/ebooks/apps" target="_blank">eBooks App</a> <a href="/mobile-apps" data-tracking-id="mobile_apps"><div class="footer-mobile-apps lazy-bgImage" data-bgImage="//img5a.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/social-sprite-b3c0ada7.png"></div></a> </div> <div class="lastUnit size1of4"> <span class="fk-footer-sub-head fk-footer-unit"><strong>Misc</strong></span> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="http://www.flipkart.com">Online Shopping</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/affiliate/" target="_blank">Affiliate</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/buy-gift-voucher">e-Gift Voucher</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/?sitevariant=mobile">Flipkart lite</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/flipkart-first">Flipkart First Subscription</a> <a class="fk-footer-unit fk-footer-link" href="/elearning-faq">eLearning FAQ</a> </div> </div> <div class="lastUnit size10f4 lpadding15 fk-trust-boosters"> <p class="fk-footer-sub-head"><strong>Safe and Secure Shopping</strong></p> <p class="bpadding15 fk-trust-content">All major credit and debit cards are accepted. We also accept payments by <strong>Internet Banking, Cash on Delivery</strong> and <strong>Equated Monthly Installments(EMI).</strong></p> </div> </div> <div class="fk-footer-ssa"> <a href="/account/orders?srcLink=footer" class="login-required"> <ul class="line ssa-block"> <li class="unit size1of3 ssa-unit"><i class="icon track-icon"></i><span class="text">Track your<br /> order</span></li> <li class="unit size1of3 ssa-unit"><i class="icon return-icon"></i><span class="text">Free &amp; easy<br /> returns</span></li> <li class="lastUnit ssa-unit"><i class="icon cancel-icon"></i><span class="text">Online<br /> cancellations</span></li> </ul> </a> </div> <div class="line fk-footer-policy"> <div class="unit tpadding5 tc-links"> <span><span class="policies-title boldtext">Policies:</span> <a href="/s/terms">Terms of use</a> | <a href="/s/paymentsecurity">Security</a> | <a
 href="/s/privacypolicy">Privacy</a> | <a
 href="https://seller.flipkart.com/fiv">Infringement</a></span> <span class="fk-footet-cr">&copy; 2007-2014 <span>Flipkart.com.</span></span> </div> <div class="fk-footer-kit unitExt fk-inline-block"> <strong class="title fk-float-left">Keep in touch</strong> <a class="facebook_icn inner rmargin5 lazy-bgImage" data-bgImage="//img5a.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/social-sprite-b3c0ada7.png" target="_blank" href="/ol?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fflipkart"></a> <a class="twitter_icn inner rmargin5 lazy-bgImage" data-bgImage="//img5a.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/social-sprite-b3c0ada7.png" target="_blank" href="/ol?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.twitter.com%2Fflipkart"></a> <a class="google-plus_icn inner fk-sprite-hf rmargin5 lazy-bgImage" data-bgImage="//img5a.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/social-sprite-b3c0ada7.png" target="_blank" href="/ol?link=https%3A%2F%2Fplus.google.com%2F109591199284807005836%2Fposts"></a> <a class="youtube_icn inner rmargin5 lazy-bgImage" data-bgImage="//img5a.flixcart.com/www/prod/images/social-sprite-b3c0ada7.png" target="_blank" href="/ol?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fflipkart"></a> </div> </div> <div class="line top-brand-links tpadding10 bpadding10"> <div class="line boldtext bpadding10 top-brands-title">
 Top Stores : <a href="/brands">Brand Directory</a> | <a href="/store-directory">Store Directory</a> </div> <div class="line"> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 Most searched for on Flipkart: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/games/call-of-duty~series/pr?sid=4rr,tg9"> Call Of Duty</a>
 | <a href="/androidone"> Android One</a>
 | <a href="/offers"> Diwali Offers</a> </div> </div> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 Mobiles: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/moto-e/p/itmdvuwsybgnbtha"> Moto E</a>
 | <a href="/q/samsung-mobiles"> Samsung Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/micromax-mobiles"> Micromax Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/nokia-mobiles"> Nokia Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/htc-mobiles"> HTC Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/sony-mobiles"> Sony Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/apple-mobiles"> Apple Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/lg-mobiles"> LG Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/q/karbonn-mobiles"> Karbonn Mobile</a>
 | <a href="/mobiles">View all</a> </div> </div> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 Camera: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/q/nikon-cameras"> Nikon Camera</a>
 | <a href="/q/canon-cameras"> Canon Camera</a>
 | <a href="/q/sony-cameras"> Sony Camera</a>
 | <a href="/cameras/samsung~brand/pr?sid=jek,p31"> Samsung Camera</a>
 | <a href="/q/canon-dslr-cameras"> Canon DSLR</a>
 | <a href="/q/nikon-dslr-cameras"> Nikon DSLR</a>
 | <a href="/cameras/dslr~type/pr?sid=jek,p31"> DSLR Camera</a>
 | <a href="/camera-accessories/lenses/pr?sid=jek,6l2,e9y"> Camera Lens</a>
 | <a href="/camera-accessories/tripods/pr?sid=jek,6l2,ce6"> Camera Tripod</a>
 | <a href="/cameras">View all</a> </div> </div> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 Laptops: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/laptops/apple~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Apple Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/acer~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Acer Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Samsung Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/lenovo-laptops"> Lenovo Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/sony-laptops"> Sony Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/dell-laptops"> Dell Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/asus~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Asus Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/toshiba~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Toshiba Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/lg~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> LG Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/hp-laptops"> HP Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/~notebook/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Notebook</a>
 | <a href="/brands/laptops?sid=6bo,b5g">View all</a> </div> </div> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 TVs: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/sony~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Sony TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/samsung~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Samsung TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/lg~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> LG TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/panasonic~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Panasonic TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/onida~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Onida TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/toshiba~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Toshiba TV</a>
 | <a href="/home-entertainment/tvs/philips~brand/pr?sid=ckf%2Cczl"> Philips TV</a>
```

The problem is that the most html pages are considered as 1 line, so on searching -:
`grep -F "my text of interest" html_file.htm`l - **if there is a match I see the whole file dumped down - which does not let me see the context - and is very painful to debug** 
Consider, I am searching for something that would occur in 1 line, if viewed in HTML, but not otherwise.

**Example** -: 
Say I need to search for "/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g" in this file , but on grep, as above, I see the whole dump(and more..) 
How can I search effectively within the html for this usecase - and get only the logical neighbouring context (`grep -A 4 -B 4` does not apply directly) - can I manipulate that to interpret the file as an html and then read the neighboring context ?

Sample output for the match -:

```
<a href="/camera-accessories/lenses/pr?sid=jek,6l2,e9y"> Camera Lens</a>
 | <a href="/camera-accessories/tripods/pr?sid=jek,6l2,ce6"> Camera Tripod</a>
 | <a href="/cameras">View all</a> </div> </div> <div class="line brands"> <div class="unit boldtext rpadding10 size1of9">
 Laptops: </div> <div class="lastUnit"> <a href="/laptops/apple~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Apple Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/acer~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Acer Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Samsung Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/lenovo-laptops"> Lenovo Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/sony-laptops"> Sony Laptop</a>
 | <a href="/q/dell-laptops"> Dell Laptop</a>
```

Preferably with the highlighted term that matched -  "/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"  in this case.

Comment: Do you want the 4 `<a>` tags before and after an `<a>` tag with a specific `href`?

Comment: Come on, do we REALLY need to read through that massive pile of input? Couldn't you reduce your input to some small sample of less than 10 lines with brief/simple tags and values that REPRESENTS your problem so we don't have to wade through all of that?

Comment: @EdMorton I wanted to highlight the point that it returns the massive pile when used using grep. You don't have to read the massive pile though :) If there's some lightweight utility to "interpret" the html as a list of separate lines, and not as 1 line , I would be happy to try (which is my original use-case)

Comment: @TomFenech We can assume there must be a pattern I am searching for.  <a< </a> in this case.

Comment: @ekta I've no idea what you mean by "if there's some lightweight...". 2 people have answered you. If you provided a more sensible sample input set many more people would bother to read your question and then provide answers. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton Lightweight means grep/awk, and like. Tom's answer meets my sue case(except the highlighting part, of the match) - but it is a custom script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using tools designed to deal with text files, use an HTML parser, such as `Mojo::DOM` for Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10";
use Mojo::DOM;
use List::Util "first";

# construct DOM object from file
my $d = Mojo::DOM->new(do { local $/; <> });

# get all <a> tags
my $a = $d->find("a");                               

# find the index of the one we are interested in
my $href = '/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g';
my $index = first { $a->[$_]->attr('href') eq $href } 0..$a->size;

# print links
say $a->slice($index-4..$index+4)->map("to_string")->join("\n");
```

Run it like `perl script.pl file.html`.

Output:

```
<a href="/camera-accessories/tripods/pr?sid=jek,6l2,ce6"> Camera Tripod</a>
<a href="/cameras">View all</a>
<a href="/laptops/apple~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Apple 
Laptop</a>
<a href="/laptops/acer~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Acer Laptop</a>
<a href="/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Samsung Laptop</a>
<a href="/q/lenovo-laptops"> Lenovo Laptop</a>
<a href="/q/sony-laptops"> Sony Laptop</a>
<a href="/q/dell-laptops"> Dell Laptop</a>
<a href="/laptops/asus~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g"> Asus Laptop</a>
```

#### The following are some untested suggestions

In order to pass options to the script, à la grep, you could use [`Getopt::Std`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Std.html):

```
use Getopt::Std;
our($opt_A, $opt_B) = (0, 0);
getopts('A:B:');
```

This would allow you to pass options `-A` and `-B` to the script, like `perl script.pl -A 4 -B 4 file.html`. You could then change the hard-coded `4`s in the code above to `($index-$opt_A..$index+$opt_B)`.

To pass in the pattern as well, you could specify another option.

To colour the output on the line you're interested in, you could use [`Term::ANSIColor`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html):

```
say $a->slice($index-4..$index-1)->map("to_string")->join("\n");
say green $a->[$index]->to_string;
say $a->slice($index+1..$index+4)->map("to_string")->join("\n");
```

Comment: Can you add something for color/highlighting,so I  accept the answer ? Also, I am thinking to run this as a shell script where I will call this perl file with a list of patterns. Actual usecase :  grep -F -A 4 -B 4 <pattern file> <html file to be searched in>  I hope that will work with little re-arrangement of this code .

Comment: @ekta unable to test these suggestions at the moment but I've added some ideas for passing options and colouring the output.

Answer (score 1):

grep as follows

```
  grep --color -F -A 4 -B 4 '/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g' 'my_file'
```

**EDIT**

since all the data are found on one line you can use grep to find the string and characters surrounding the string

```
grep -o --color '.\{0,3\}/laptops/samsung~brand/pr?sid=6bo,b5g.\{0,3\}
```

This will find the pattern and print 3 chars before and after the string

`.` before and after the string represents any character except newline char.

Comment: How is that going to change anything?

Comment: I tried using the OP way and it didn't work..I tried it this way and it worked

Comment: I see..i think it is the command line used by the OP..answer edited

Comment: @Xong It will still return the whole file since it is treated as one line file, so saying -A 4 And -B 4 will return the whole file.

Comment: ok..i see...since all the data are on one line in the html file, I have edit my answer using grep to find surrounding chars around the pattern.